# Webcam applications prevent screen from dimming and locking

Tags: 18.04, brightness, webcam, lock-screen, cheese

I want to use my laptop webcam as a security camera, and I would like my screen to dim and lock as always during the webcam app is running (`cheese` or `guvcview`). Currently these applications prevent screen from dimming and locking and once I quit them everything works as before. How can I make my screen dim and lock as always when these apps are running? Thank you!

UPDATE:
When I press WinKey+L, it does lock the screen, but dims and turns off the display only once, so when I wake it up, it never turns off again.

Comment: Can you lock it with Super ("Windows" key) + L?

Comment: Yes, it locks, dims and turns off.

Comment: Yes, it locks, but dims and turns off only once - when I wake it up, it never dims and turns off again